# How to get class loader for class by It's name in OSGI?

Tags: osgi, classloader

How can I get class loader for given class by It's name in OSGI?
The class is declared in another package, and may be not exported.

Comment: Maybe you can explain why you want to do this, so that we can find another solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basically impossible because the name of a class is not enough to uniquely identify it. Multiple modules may contain classes with the same name; this is an inevitable property of any module system that provides module isolation.

In fact it's theoretically impossible in "ordinary" Java as well, because the identity of a class consists of its fully-qualified name AND its ClassLoader. So you're asking how to get half of the identity of a class given only the other half.

If you do know which bundle/module contains the class, then you can load the class from that bundle with `Bundle.loadClass("Foo")` and from the Class object you can call `getClassLoader()`.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to load the class from the other bundle? The cleaner way would be to instantiate the class in the bundle that contains it and publish it as a service. Or if you need more than one instance you could register a Factory as a service.